# Repeat a function inside that function a certain time

Tags: python

Is there any way to reduce this code? It repeats itself, but I cannot find any way to reduce it because it is only repeating inside one elif. Sorry I'm a beginner my code is quite bad

```
while t:
    input("Appuyez sur entrer pour continuer...")
    for a in range(nb):
        while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21 or 11 in joueurs[a]:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("main du joueur", a + 1, ":", joueurs[a], "Total :", sum(joueurs[a]))
            if sum(joueurs[a]) > 21 and 11 in joueurs[a]:
                onze(joueurs)
                print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
            ask = input("Joueur {} voulez vous une carte ?(oui/non)".format(a + 1))
            if ask == "oui":
                askoui(joueurs)
            else:
                asknon()
                t = False
                break
        if sum(joueurs[a]) == 21:
            print("joueur", a + 1, "a BLACKJACK")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21 and 11 in joueurs[a]:
            onze(joueurs)
            print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
            time.sleep(1)
            while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21 or 11 in joueurs[a]: #it repeats itelf here
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("main du joueur", a + 1, ":", joueurs[a], "Total :", sum(joueurs[a]))
                if sum(joueurs[a]) > 21 and 11 in joueurs[a]:
                    onze(joueurs)
                    print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
                ask = input("Joueur {} voulez vous une carte ?(oui/non)".format(a + 1))
                if ask == "oui":
                    askoui(joueurs)
                else:
                    asknon()
                    t = False
                    break
            elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21:
                perdu(joueurs)
                t = False
        elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21:
            perdu(joueurs)
            t = False
```

Comment: You're asking for open-ended refactoring of working code; this is suited for CodeReview, not StackOverflow.  You also need to *define* your problem; asking for wholesale "reduce this code" shows more than you need to practice programming, or ask about one particular code block.

Comment: If you find yourself repeating code, the usual solution is to put it into a function.

Comment: Ok I'll use CodeReview sorry. @Barmar I tried putting it into a function but I couldn't stop it so It would never finish

Comment: I mean just the parts that you duplicate, like `while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21 or 11 in joueurs[a]:`